# Am I getting MITM'd?

Tags: man-in-the-middle

Recently I've noticed a delay in my Internet speed.

Pages seem to start loading a little later than they used to.

I decided to do a speed test on [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/), but it wouldn't do the speed test and gave this error:

[image: Your computer's firewall or a proxy server is blocking communication over port 8080]

I'm using Wi-Fi and I can access my router's default gateway login. Although it seems to load slowly as well.

Is there any way to check whether there is some kind of MITM attack happening?

Comment: Is your computer's firewall blocking port 8080?

Comment: Nothing in this question suggests that this is caused by a MITM attack as suggested. It might be caused for example by bad network connectivity to the router, high load on the router due to some other users or bugs, a large download/upload by some system in the network etc. When something unusual happens don't suspect first a hack but try to exclude more likely causes first, i.e. reset your router, connect with cable instead of through WiFi, look at the router logs for unusual entries, check if your system itself might doing some downloads (software update?), try from different devices ... .

Answer (score 1):

> Pages seem to start loading a little later than they used to.

Treat this as latency, so review your ping. You can check your ping time against a server from the command line: Command Prompt (Windows), Terminal (OS X) and Linux, well too many for me to list off. Ping Google's public DNS server 8.8.8.8, as it is well documented, and has known response times. Via the Internet connection, I am currently connected to, a VDSL line my Speed Test result is:

[image: Speed Test with 7ms ping]

Note the ping of 7ms via fdcservers.net. Below you will see ping results from Google's public DNS server 8.8.8.8.

```
safesploit$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=122 time=10.788 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=9.498 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=9.502 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=122 time=9.685 ms
```

Do give margin, but this is a good response time (6-12ms) for VDSL and hybrid fibre-coaxial.

> Is there any way to check whether there is some kind of MITM attack happening?

You can check if a MITM attack is being performed on your LAN by checking your ARP table. See [Detecting man-in-the-middle attacks?](https://superuser.com/questions/81832/detecting-man-in-the-middle-attacks) as this is quite an involved topic, and it has already been answered. Outside your network, a Trace Route might be advisable, although it becomes particularly more difficult.

As suggested port 8080 might be blocked. You can either use NMap to port scan, connect using the Tor Browser bundle and specific for Tor to use port 8080 and see, or use [OONI](https://ooni.torproject.org/) by Tor.